# Is it possible to turn-off verifications related to a user logging in from a new IP address?

Tags: account, remote-access, grant-login-access

I am creating temporary user accounts to train new users and am using a single email address to manage these accounts. The issue is that it appears Salesforce notices if a user is accessing the site from a new IP address and is sending a verification code to the user's email; that is, my master email account for temporary users, then requires me to forward the verification emails to each user.

I realize that normally a control like this would be good, but is there a way to turn it off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may either add a range, or multiple ranges, to your org's network access list, or add IP login restrictions to that user's profile. You can't disable this feature entirely.